# Problem running Elasticsearch for Magento project on Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

I'm trying set up **Elasticsearch** for Magento 2.4.2 project. I have installed Elasticsearch 7.9.3 and openjdk 11.0.10.
I got the error:

**sudo systemctl start elasticsearch:**

```
*Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

In the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml network settings are:
**network.host:** 127.0.0.1
**http.port:** 9200
```

**journalctl -xe** command result:

```
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 10 16:10:46 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 10 16:10:46 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 10277 and the job result is failed.
Mar 10 16:10:46 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 sudo[21081]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 16:15:06 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 sudo[21568]:  : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/elasticsearch/>
Mar 10 16:15:06 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 sudo[21568]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 16:15:25 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 sudo[21568]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 16:15:52 -ThinkPad-P15s-Gen-1 wpa_supplicant[853]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Group rekeying completed with ac:cf:85:db:37:ce [GTK=CCMP]
```

**Looked through all the articles, but none of them helps to fix the situation. Сan someone suggest an idea for a solution to this problem ?**

Comment: if you faced issue to install specific version of elastic search then, see https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-install-and-setup-elasticsearch-for-magento-2-ubuntu/841 , & also see deb repo method at official site https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/deb.html#deb-repo

Answer (score 0):

The error data you shared is just identifying the error as 'exited'. This brings me to the guess work to help you with the issue.

From the Elasticsearch.yaml configuration, the port on which the Elasticsearch exposes its API is on 9200. One possibility is that the port might be pre-occupied. Can you look at the port status on your system and confirm it.

Elasticsearch.service file has configurations for memory and CPU. May be the configured memory is not sufficient for it to start.

Hope this helps. For detailed and straight forward instructions on how to install the Magento 2.4.2 this [blog](https://tryandtip.com/2021/05/16/install-magento-2-4-2-on-ubuntu-20-04/) written by me might help you.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article. When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Addressed it Cigien :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I notice this is your second answer linking to your blog, so I should point out that even if you disclose affiliation to the linked resources, promoting your content repeatedly and/or needlessly could be considered to be spam. 2 answers is fine, but I would suggest avoiding linking to your blog. Your answers don't seem to really need it anyway, and that does count as needless promotion.

Comment: I understand the reason for concern of promotion. But there is a valid reason I included the blog link. If followed everything in order as per blog, basically one should not run into the issues reported here. May be I should have mentioned that in my answers to avoid this unnecessary confusion. Sorry for that. I ll take this as pointers for my next answer related to this. Thank you

Comment: All answers need to be self-complete and stand on their own, especially given the risk of the link going bad (which happens more often than you might think). In this vein, avoid depending on blog links in answers.